# Как узнать номер последней строки или ID последней строки

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Как узнать номер последней строки или ID последней строки?
Предположим у меня вот такая таблицa:
ID  NAME      E-mail      PASS
 1
 2
 3
 4
Так вот, как мне сообщить скрипту номер последней строки или ID последней строки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял, то:

1) ID последней строки:

```
select max(id) from table
```

2) Номер последней строки = общее кол-во строк:

```
select count(*) from table
```

Замечу что в реальной работе - вариант 2 очень редко необходим ( когда работа идёт со строками, а не множествами )

Comment: A "max(id)" Писать как MAX(id) или max(id)?

Comment: без разницы... Некоторые ( в т.ч. я ) пишут с большой, что-бы сразу видеть где имена полей/таблиц, а где конструкции sql

Т.е

    SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table

Answer (score -1):

^Выше бред

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

В этом случае, что бы не хранилось в полях, вытянется последняя строка.

Comment: все норм выше

Comment: @Elime, будьте аккуратнее с высказываниями, вы в приличном месте...

Как-бы, ваш ответ не соответствует вопросу...

Comment: чем это он не соответствует?

Comment: Если и писать так как предлагаете вы (я сам так обычно пишу), то надо было написать:

     SELECT id FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1

У вас же выбираются все поля последнего ряда таблицы.

Comment: Вопрос: Как узнать номер последней строки или ID последней строки
Вы отвечаете на вопрос: Как получить последнюю строку при сортировке по ID

Comment: Вообще-то `select max(id) from table` вернет то-же что и `SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` если id будет  auto_increment.

Так что не совсем понятна претензия...Если результат **такой-же**, то что не так?

Про номер последней строки я не написал ни слова и я писал коммент а не ответ

Comment: ID идет по порядку в таблице

Comment: ID идут по порядку пока не будет удалена  одна из записей ;)

Comment: так я думал ему все поля нужны, зачем он их тогда показывал:

    ID NAME E-mail PASS

А если в таблице будет несколько сотен тысяч записей? как думаете, что быстрее сработает? Подсчет всех строк или сразу вытащить одну строку?

Хотя, этот спор уже ни к чему, мы уже увидели, зачем автору это нужно было, в теме выше :D

Comment: Подсчёта строк - даже не производиться, у mysql это число есть.

При индексе на `id`:

    SELECT MAX(id) FROM table

Медленнее чем `count(*)`, но всё-же быстрее чем

    SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Вот тут я не знаю т.к. стараюсь отходить от SQL БД, тем не менее был бы благодарен за пруфф.
*****
Я же написал - стараюсь отходить от SQL БД, мне это не так интересно.

Comment: @timka_s, точно, я перепутал с mysql_num_rows(); oO

Comment: @AlexWindHope, А что мешает взять microtime(1); и замерить время выполнения той и иной конструкции?

------------------------------------------------------

А чем вам SQL БД не нравится? На что хотите перейти?

P.S спрашиваю чисто из интереса.